Alternative proof for absolute convergence implying convergence
After some time away from maths, I'm revisiting real analysis. At the current moment, I'm going through sequences and series, and reach the well known result about absolute convergence of a series implying "regular" convergence of it.
I know that the usual proof uses triangle inequality and the fact that the sequence of partials sums of the absolute values of the terms of the absolute convergence series is Cauchy.
When going through it again, a different proof idea came to my mind... since I'm a bit away from maths, I'd like to check if what I though is correct or there are flaws in it. Here it is.
Theorem
If $\sum |a_n|$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges.
Idea
Let $S_n = \sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|$ and $T_n = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i$.
We can write $T_n$ as $T_n = T_n^{\text{pos}} - T_n^{\text{neg}}$ where:
$$
T_n^{\text{pos}} = \sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i \quad\text{where}\quad \alpha_i=\begin{cases}a_i, & \text{if } a_i \geq 0\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
$$
T_n^{\text{neg}} = \sum_{i=0}^n \beta_i \quad\text{where}\quad \beta_i=\begin{cases}-a_i, & \text{if } a_i < 0\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Since $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then $S_n$ is bounded above by some $M \in \mathbb R$.
Now, since $T_n \leq S_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, it follows that $T_n$ is also bounded above by $M$.
Both $T_n^{\text{pos}}$ and $T_n^{\text{neg}}$ are monotone increasing sequences, and since both are $\leq S_n$ for every index, both are bounded above by $M$, therefore both converges, to let say $P$ and $N$.
With that said, we have:
$$
\lim T_n = \lim T_n^{\text{pos}} - T_n^{\text{neg}} = P - N
$$
which converges, implying that $\sum a_n$ converges.
Intuition on where it might fail
I vaguely remember that we need to be careful when changing order of terms in infinite sums, so, even though for any $n \in \mathbb N$ we have $T_n = T_n^{\text{pos}} - T_n^{\text{neg}}$, it might not be the case that the infinite sum $\sum a_n$ (which is the limit of $T_n$) equals to $\lim T_n^{\text{pos}} - T_n^{\text{neg}}$, since the terms on the latter are in a different order.

Thanks for reading and any discussion will be highly appreciated.

The fact that $(U_n-V_n)$ is bounded does not imply that $(U_n)$ and $(V_n)$ are both bounded.

@hamam_Abdallah, You're right, I need to rephrase that... but isn't the conclusion that both $T_n^{\text{pos}}$ and $T_n^{\text{neg}}$ are bounded true? You can see that from a different perspective, i.e, $T_n^{\text{pos}} \leq S_n$ and $T_n^{\text{neg}} \leq S_n$ for every index...

@BrunoReis Yes, the conclusion is true but the argument is wrong. So you should edit your question to use the argument you gave in the comment.

You can use that $S_n + T_n = 2 T_n^+$ and $S_n-T_n = 2T_n^-$ for your definition to avoid the complications involved with reordering the series since it's well-defined for all $n$. So set $T_n^\pm = (S_n\pm T_n)/2$ which also gives you an easy way to argue the boundedness.

@jjagmath, done :)

@CyclotomicField, nice, ty.

Also note that your argument shows that $|\sum_n a_n| \leq \sum_n |a_n|$ since $|\sum_n a_n|$ is given as the difference of two nonnegative quantities bounded by $ \sum_n |a_n|$.

Thanks for everyone who commented out, but it's still not clear for me if, after fixing the argument on boudness of the positive / negative parts, if there are flaws or the proof is indeed correct.
